# Difference trunk vs master branch after svn to git migration

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I performed an svn to git migration. I see my branches + a lot of additional trunk branches. How do I have to interpret those branches? I already have a master (which I've defined as the trunk with `--trunk dev`).

When I show my branches I have something like this:

```
* master
  prod
  test
  trunk@123
  trunk@432
  trunk@892
  trunk@1023
  trunk@1134
```

While my master is the dev branch in svn (we defined dev as our trunk).

Comment: Try `git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate` to check the relationship between these branches. Besides, you could test if a trunk branch has already been merged into `master` by `git branch --contains trunk@123`. If the output contains `master`, then `trunk@123` could be removed if you don't need it anymore.

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks, well I seems to contain master and some other trunk@revision branches each time. So this means those branches are merged with the master? But are this real branches because we never had a branch called trunk.

Comment: @ElpieKay Can I delete local and remote branches without losing commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git-svn` creates the branches with `@`*revision* suffix when the changeset on *branch* in *revision* is not parent of the changeset on *branch* in *revision*+1.

That is, you get `trunk@123` if the next change  to `/trunk` after 123 (not necessarily 124; as that can concern different path) deleted it and replaced it with new content, likely by copying it from `/branches/dev` (or `/dev` or how you had it called).

In Subversion, changes live on branches, so you can always access that state as `trunk@123`, but in Git, commits are only linked in the DAG, so since these commits have no successor (as the branch was rewritten from elsewhere), the commits would not be accessible without these branch labels.

Comment: thanks, now I tried the same and defined --nobranches and still I get svn/remotes/trunk@revision in my branches list. They are still there because otherwise git will miss commits?

Comment: @DenCowboy, with `--nobranches` you are just telling it not to bother with things under `/branches`. But since you are still importing `/trunk`, you still get these as it is the only way to make the commits available in git, yes.

Comment: Just a note of clarification: git-svn does a pretty hard attempt at getting all history of branches that you ask it to track... and that means going back in history as far as it can. If you set it up to track branch _trunk_ and at some point it sees that a different branch is merged into _trunk_ but is from a path git-svn is _not_ configured to track then it creates a branch like trunk@some-revision (that's the revision where the merge happened).

Comment: You can try deleting them with git branch -d (or -D) but that won't suffice. git will recreate them because they are "hidden" in metadata (it's a pain to get rid of them, actually).